# Find expectation and calculate Chernoff bound

Tags: algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms, chernoff-bounds

We have a group of employees and their company will assign a prize to as many employees as possible by finding the ones probably better than the rest. The company assigned the same 2 tasks to every employee and scored their results with 2 values x,y both in [0,1]. The company selects the best employees among the others, if there is no other employee with a better score in both tasks.

Knowing that both scores are uniformly distributed in [0,1], how can i proof that the number of the employees receiving the price is estimated near to logn, with n the number of the employees, having high probability?

I need to use Chernoff bound to bound the probability, that the number of winning employees is higher than logn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find expectation with Chernoff bound](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119135/find-expectation-with-chernoff-bound)

Comment: yes, I created a new account and could not comment. But my question is : How can i calculate Chernoff Bounds now ?

Comment: Please don't re-ask your question more than once.  If you accidentally created multiple accounts, you can merge them using https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't because I wasn't logged in when I asked the question